# CodeDeploy fails in ApplcationStop coz not able to Kill process

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have been using the same script and it used to work before. Due to another error previously,
I deleted the application folder from the console. (The application was killed successfully in the previous deploy but there was an error in AfterInstall)

stop_bot.sh:

```
#!bin/bash

ps -ef | grep testMain.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Error:

```
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/stop_bot.sh
[stderr]kill: not enough arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `grep testMain.py` *does not return any values*. You have to double check your programs and ensure that `grep testMain.py` (or whatever it should be) actually provides a list of processes to be killed.

Comment: It doesn't return anything in the console

Comment: @DeadPool That's what I said. You have to modify the command to return correct values. Only you know what python programs you are running and how.